# Связь двух таблиц и выпадающий список

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите начинающему!

Есть две таблицы:

```
tab1
id
produkt
```

-в эту таблицу добавляются клиенты

```
tab2
id name
1 продукт1
2 продукт2
3 продукт3
```

-эта таблица должна выводиться в выпадающий список.

Внимание вопрос: как сделать, чтоб одно из name таблицы два (скажем продукт2) из выпадающего списка вносилось при внесении таблицы1. То есть, заполняя таблицу1, выбирается из выпадающего списка красное и вносится. 
Также при редактировании в браузере данных из таблицы1 должна быть возможность отредактировать продукт.

Просто вывести из двух таблиц в браузер данные как-то могу. А с редактированием и выпадающим списокм проблема. 
Прошу о помощи!

Answer (score 1):

Делаете выборку данных с таблицы 2. Далее форичем вносите их в select, примерно выглядит так:

```
 <!-- тут остальная часть формы -->
    <select name="produkt">
        <? foreach ($produkts as $produkt): ?>
        <option value="<?= $produkt->id ?>"><?= $produkt->name ?></option>
        <? endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<!-- тут остальная часть формы -->
```

Ловите свою форму и вносите в бд.

Comment: попробовал. почему то не получилось. Думаю, у меня ещё не достаточно знаний.